# How to access a file without it being open and copy rows based on text in column?

Tags: excel, vba, row

The below code opens up folders and allows me to choose what document I want to be the source, it then opens it behind screen and works when copying sheets.

I tried to change the code to copy rows based on column G having "140. On Hold" in it, then pasting each of these rows into the active workbook.

UPDATED CODE

```
Sub GetBIDFileCopyData()

Dim Fname As String
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim DestWbk As Workbook
Dim C As Range
Dim J As Long

Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

SrcWbk.Sheets("ChangeDetails").Rows(C.Row).Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Bids On-Hold 29.01.20").Rows(J)
J = 1
For Each C In SrcWbk.Range("G2:G200")
    If C.Value = "140. On Hold" Then
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next C

SrcWbk.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: What are `SrcWbk.Sheets ("ChangeDetails")` and `DestWbk.Sheets ("Bid Delivery Report")` supposed to do?

Comment: Two issues i see are `Dim J As Integar`.  First the spelling is incorrect and also its best to use `As Long`, So i would refactor using `Dim J As Long` also instead of `If C = "140. On Hold" Then` use `If C.Value = "140. On Hold" Then`.

Comment: compile error is returned when I try to run it? fyi i'm using Excel 2010

Comment: Use Autofilter as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s/11633207#11633207)

Comment: that's all a bit confusing, however I need to keep the option in where I choose the source file, as the name of it changes every week due to the dates on it changing. Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SiddharthRout commented, the best way to copy/paste based on a specific criteria, is to use a filter. Comments are given in the code below. I did not test your code to open a file.

```
Dim Fname As String, SrcWbk As Workbook, DestWS As Worksheet, Rng As Range 'Assign your variables

    'Set your destination worksheet
    Set DestWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bids On-Hold 29.01.20")

    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")

        If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub

    Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

    'Set the range you want to filter on your scorce worksheet
    Set Rng = SrcWbk.Sheets("ChangeDetails").Range("G2:G200")

    'Since you used only column G for your range, use the copy line below.
    'But if you use the full range of the worksheet, e.g. Range("A1:Z200"),
    'you could use field:=7 in the filter, and remove .EntireRow from the copy line

        With Rng
            'Filter Column G
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="140. On Hold"
            'use Resize and Offset to copy the visible data
            'If Row 2 has data and is not a header row, you should use Row 1, in Rng
            'Offset and Resize adjusts the range so the top row(Header) is not copied
            Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
            DestWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Clear the filter    
        .AutoFilter
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The two lines

```
SrcWbk.Sheets ("ChangeDetails")
DestWbk.Sheets ("Bid Delivery Report")
```

do not compile. What are they supposed to do?

You try to copy the rows with the following code:

```
SrcWbk.Rows(C.Row).Copy DestWbk.Rows(J)
```

but you are missing a reference to the worksheet.

So maybe you are looking for:

```
    SrcWbk.Sheets("ChangeDetails").Rows(C.Row).Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Bid Delivery Report").Rows(J)
```

or better use varables for your sheets.

Comment: Still not working, the above code works better, however I get Application-defined or Object-defined error returned?? I am new to VBA to very unsure, so bare with me.